# compare column to atributes in a loop in pyqgis processing

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing

I am creating a script in processing qgis. I am running the interpolation algorithm.I have two tables table A and table B. Table A contains attributes like A_test,B_test up to Z_test. Table B contains columns A_test,D_test. How can I programmatically compare the attributes from table A to the columns in table B. The table B will always be different and can contain all values in table A or limited values. The syntax I had in mind was a for loop with condition

`if table A.attribute = table B.column

    then run algorithm else

     raise exception`

Comment: Please clarify: do you want to compare attribute values with column names?

Comment: yes, I want to compare attributes to column names